# C# 10: Don't I need using System anymore?

Tags: c#

I have just made a new console project in C# and I'm wondering why `Console.WriteLine("");` works without `using System` in the top.

Since when did the using System become optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some standard usings are defined in a global file now for convenience and are part of some of the new project templates:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/

*Edit:* This article dives a little deeper into the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates

Generally, starting with .NET 6.0 implicit usings are enabled in new project templates for commonly used namespaces. It can be disabled in the project file.